# Push Button to the bottom of container (justify-self-end Not working)

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I want to push the button to the end of the flex container

Components Code

```
<div className="group flex flex-col gap-4 rounded-2xl bg-brand-white p-4 shadow-card">
    <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-2xl">
      { ...JSX }
    </div>

    <p className="text-brand-black/80">{shortDescription}</p>
    <Button
      as={Link}
      href={link}
      variant="sm-inverted"
      className="w-fit justify-self-end"
    >
      Learn More
    </Button>
  </div>
```

[image]

justify-self-end is not working and self end pushes the button to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class "flex-1" to your `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ml-auto

so it should be className="w-fit ml-auto"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap then please correct classes name. Like: d-flex
then insted of using "justify-self-end" try to use "justify-content-end"

```
<div className="group d-flex flex-col gap-4 rounded-2xl bg-brand-white p-4 shadow-card justify-content-between">
        <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-2xl">
          { ...JSX }
        </div>
    
        <p className="text-brand-black/80">{shortDescription}</p>
        <Button
          as={Link}
          href={link}
          variant="sm-inverted"
          className="w-fit justify-content-end"
        >
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the content in a div or another tag at the same level as your button and then just add `justify-between` to the first div classname. Just make sure that the content is ok after that.

```
<div className="group flex flex-col gap-4 rounded-2xl bg-brand-white p-4 shadow-card justify-between">
  <div>
    <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-2xl">
      { ...JSX }
    </div>

    <p className="text-brand-black/80">{shortDescription}</p>
  </div>
  <Button
    as={Link}
    href={link}
    variant="sm-inverted"
    className="w-fit justify-self-end"
  >
    Learn More
  </Button>
</div>
```